# Unable to use 'bundle exec rake db:migrate' command on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

I'm 50 pages into 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial' and it instructs me to run the bundle exec rake db:migrate command. When I do, I get the below answer. I don't know if running the command with --trace gives any helpful info.

It seems that it has to do with using postgresql, but after that I'm completely over my head.

What can I do to get this to work?

Thanks a ton!

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\demo_app>bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/1
0061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Sites\rails_projects\demo_app>bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/1
0061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:548:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_c
onnection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connec
tion'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in check
out'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in conne
ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_conne
ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:863:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:165:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: has an installed and launch `postgresql`?

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused

Comment: Do you have a `config/database.yml`? Not `config/database.yml.example`.

Comment: @Monk_Code I'm pretty sure I do. How do I check?

Comment: @Dunken Thanks! I play with that post, but since it's geared for Mac and I'm using a Windows machine it wasn't as helpful as I'd like.

Comment: @Nerve I do. Although after seeing this [Gist database.yml example](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/961978#file-database-yml-example-postresql) I'm not sure I modified it correctly.

Comment: I may have found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066935/rails-activerecord-adapternotspecified-even-though-it-is I'll have to check after I get some sleep.

Comment: can you post your `database.yml` ?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a possible duplicate of

[PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)

I quess you'll find your answer there, but because you are on windows you might not.

I developed rails on windows for a while. It is pure pain. Just wait until you get into testing

You should install [viritualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) (or other unix based operating system) and do you rails development from there.

Here are some links to get you started with vbox( short for viritualbox)

http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox

Comment: Thanks! I did check out that post and the differences in OS does make a difference, so it wasn't as helpful as I'd like. My issue has to do with postgresql, because my app where I used the default, sqlite3, works. I just don't know anything about postgresql to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Developing Rails on Windows is indeed pure pain. I've experienced the same.

Answer (score 0):

Only after I reach out for help do I realize that I misread my tutorial. /facepalm

My tutorial asked me to add

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

instead of doing that, I replaced `gem 'sqlite3'` with `gem 'pg'` and that caused mass confusion and hysteria which caused the `rake` command not to work correctly.

Thanks everyone for your help!