# developement database is not configured

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I solve this problem I am facing this problem on the server in development mode?

developement database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

database.yml

```
  default: &default
    adapter: sqlite3
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

  development:
    <<: *default
    database: db/development.sqlite3


  test:
    <<: *default
    database: db/test.sqlite3

  production:
    <<: *default
    database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Its possible you did not specify the database, it should perhaps be "development"? Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066935/rails-activerecord-adapternotspecified-even-though-it-is

Comment: Check your `config/database.yml` file and see if it contains configuration for the development environment. There should be something like what @محمد pointed in his comment.

Comment: @محمد check my database.yml file.

Comment: @KKB most probably is that you are typing the work `development` wrongly.

Comment: @TamerShlash not use any extra "e". i fount also this error  on page.

.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'

Comment: @KKB the extra "e" is in the value of your Environment Variable called `RAILS_ENV`, you can see it by opening a terminal window and typing `echo $RAILS_ENV`, and you can set its's value to the correct value with `RAILS_ENV=development`. Are you using a tutorial on configuring a rails development server? if so, please add link to it.

Comment: @TamerShlash i try echo $RAILS_ENV on console it will return development.  No i am not use any tutorial.
 I use rake db:create db:migrate db:seed RAILS_ENV=development
for create db and migration and seed file load.

Comment: @محمد not work database.yml.

Comment: @KKB put `RAILS_ENV=development` at the beginning of the command instead of at the end, i.e `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:create`.

Comment: @TamerShlash RAILS_ENV=development rake db:create also not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your database.yml :

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

You are typing the word `developement` instead of the word `development`. (no extra `e` between `p` and `m`).